# Css transition left and right position for one element

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have the following css code:

```
#masthead {
    transition: left linear 0.25s;
    -moz-transition: left linear 0.25s;
    -o-transition: left linear 0.25s;
    -webkit-transition: left linear 0.25s;
    -ms-transition: left linear 0.25s;
    transition: right linear 0.25s;
    -moz-transition: right linear 0.25s;
    -o-transition: right linear 0.25s;
    -webkit-transition: right linear 0.25s;
    -ms-transition: right linear 0.25s;
}
```

I would like to transition  both left and right positions.
But it's not working as expected.
I realise this is because I can't have the same property declaration in the css selector.

So I thought maybe I could do this, but it's still not working :(

```
#masthead {
    transition: left, right linear 0.25s;
    -moz-transition: left, right linear 0.25s;
    -o-transition: left, right linear 0.25s;
    -webkit-transition: left, right linear 0.25s;
    -ms-transition: left, right linear 0.25s;
}
```

I also tried: `transition: all linear 0.25s;`
but here is the problem, when the page is scrolled the header becomes sticky and there is a top bar 25px high at the top of the header. so the header transitions to the top when the topbar is hidden on scroll.
I also have to off canvas menus which slide out on the left and right side, and when they do the header gets pushed to the left or right depending on which off canvas menu is triggered.

It is the pushing of the header left or right, with `position: left/right` which I want to trigger. But not the `position: top`

How would I go about this.

[W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp) doesn't seem to provide the solution. I think it may not be possible.

Cheers

Comment: have you tried with transition: all linear 0.25s; ?? I know that's gonna be for all kind of transition but maybe it solves your issue!

Comment: @JVLobo Cheers for the help. See my updated answer, unfortunatly it won't help me on this occasion :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to repeat the attributes. So instead of

```
transition: left, right linear 0.25s;
```

try

```
transition: left linear 0.25s, right linear 0.25s;
```

Comment: Works a charm, didn't realise you could repeat the attributes. Cheers bud :)